# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-annotations

Use jdk 1.8

1. SpringMVC-4.3.3
2. SpringCore-4.3.3
3. javax.servlet-api-3.0.1
4. spring-data-jpa:1.10.4
5. hibernate-entitymanager:4.2.5.Final
6. hibernate-core:4.2.5.Final
7. Simple Logging Facade for Java:1.6.1

I encountered with such error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation

**My question**:
Why error encoured and how fix it?

*web.xml*

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>product</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>product</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*product-servlet.xml*

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kopylov.spring.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

*Controller*

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class ProductController {

@RequestMapping
public String showHome(){
    return "home";
}
```

}

*AppInitializer*

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
```

public class AppInitializer extends            AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses(){
    return new Class<?>[]{
            DataConfig.class
    };
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){
    return new Class<?>[0];
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings(){
    return new String[0];
}
```

}

*DataConfig*

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.kopylov.spring")
@PropertySource("classpath:/com/kopylov/spring/resources/app.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.kopylov.spring.repository")
public class DataConfig {
private static final String PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
private static final String PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
private static final String PROP_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
private static final String PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";
private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "db.hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "db.hibernate.dialect";
private static final String PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
private static final String PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";

@Resource
private Environment env;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(){
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(){
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfb.setDataSource(dataSource());
    emfb.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistence.class);
    emfb.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
    emfb.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());
    return emfb;
}

@Bean
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
}

private Properties getHibernateProperties(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
    properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    properties.put(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO, env.getRequiredProperty(PROP_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
    return properties;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have forgot to import your product-servlet to configuration class

you could move your product-servlet.xml to 'resources' so that it is available in classpath

so your servlet mapping looks like this

```
<servlet>  
        <servlet-name>product</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:/product-servlet.xml</param-value>
         </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet> 
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>product</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in your config class

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScan("com.kopylov.spring")
    @PropertySource("classpath:/com/kopylov/spring/resources/app.properties")
    @EnableJpaRepositories("com.kopylov.spring.repository")
    @ImportResource("classpath:/product-servlet.xml")
    public class DataConfig {
    //..
    }
```

BTW, better not to mix match xml and java configuration. As java config has become norm, you could use **WebMvcConfigurerAdapter**

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/gradle-spring-4-mvc-hello-world-example-annotation/

Answer (score 1):

Perfect solution worked for me :

**Add commons-configuration-1.6.jar to the lib directory**

Answer (score 0):

I dont think your dispatcher is configured correctly in your web.xml.  You do not have any `<init-param>` tags.  See docs

http://docs.spring.io/spring-flex/docs/1.0.x/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Try editing to:

`<servlet>
        <servlet-name>product</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
           <init-param>
               <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
               <param-value>/WEB-INF/product-servlet.xml</param-value>
           </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>`

*EDIT for additional info*
Also, I believe you will need to add some mapping to your @RequestMapping annotation, see link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping

Answer (score 0):

```
First clean your project and build again. Check whether you are getting this error.


Then Check with this: nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotatedElementUtils.hasAnnotation
```

I think you have missed some repositories in pom.xml or multiple jars of different versions in your pom.xml. Sometimes your spring jars not match mutually with each other.

Add this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Remove   4.3.3.RELEASE from all spring dependencies.

Refer: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html (Read: Maven "Bill Of Materials" Dependency)

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if all of the build path errors are resolved or not.
In most of this kind of cases spring initializer throws this error if build path errors are not resolved.